# List of all keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an official list of keyboard shortcuts.  The main elementary website shows a few but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Juno you can press the super key to see the shortcuts overlay. 
This won't include app specific shortcuts, but we're working hard to make those more discoverable:
https://github.com/orgs/elementary/projects/32

Comment: Thanks! As a complete noob to elementary it'd be good to see a list of shortcuts etc so good luck on the above link